# How to show chat.html overlay on home.html in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have two pages in my Ionic project:

- home.html
- chat.html

I want to show chat.html over home.html on right side bottom as a chat window. How can I achieve this?

I have tried to portray in a image what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: add chat.html dynamically in your home.html file.
Then if your condition is true then it will show in home.html .
Also you have to provide both file z-index to overlay your chat.html

Comment: how to add it dynamically ?  and how to make it look like a window , can yu point me to something similar, or some basic code

Answer (score 1):

you can set chat.html as modal or popover and determine it's position, height and width above home.html

Answer (score 0):

try like below code

**home.html**

```
  <button ion-button block (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SampleModalPage } from '../sample-modal/sample-modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) { }

  openModal() {
    let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SampleModalPage);
    myModal.present();
  }
}
```

**chat.html**

```
---- chat code -----
<button ion-button block (click)="closeModal()">Close Modal</button>
```

**chat.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-sample-modal',
  templateUrl: 'sample-modal.html'
})
export class SampleModalPage {
  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

  closeModal() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

if you want to pass some data into `chat.html`

```
openModal() {
  let obj = {userId: '1', name: 'xyz', email: 'xyz@gmail.com'};
  let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SampleModalPage, obj);
  myModal.present();
}
```

you can get data in `chat.html`

```
 export class SampleModalPage {
      email: string;

      constructor(public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}
        this.email = this.navParams.get('email');
    }
```

Comment: Ok, i have tested the above code, it disables the back page, what we want is , we should be able to chat and background page should not be disabled so that we can work on both pages , screenshot attached -  https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzm6uteadlo8u55/Screenshot%202017-12-15%2016.35.46.png?dl=0 , `whats the solution for this ?`

Answer (score 0):

first, if your `homepage` is using ionic `lazyload`, you need to import `ChatPage` in `home.module.ts` , it'll look like this

home.module.ts

```
...
import { ChatPageModule} from '../chat/chat.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(BackgroundPage),
    ChatPageModule
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

then, just add `ChatPage` selector where you want it, for example:

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div class="chat-container">
        <page-chat></page-chat>
    </div>
    <button ion-button (click)="onClickTest()">Test Click</button>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
onClickTest(){
    console.log("I'm fine");
}
```

home.css

```
.chat-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    bottom: 16px;
}
```

---

chat.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChatPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ChatPage),
  ],
  exports:[
    ChatPage
  ]
})
export class ChatPageModule {}
```

chat.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    CHAT PAGE
    <button ion-button (click)="onClickChat()">in Chat</button>
</ion-content>
```

chat.ts

```
onClickChat(){
    console.log("from chat with love");
  }
```

try it, hope this can help :)

Comment: i will implement this and get back